# Get a User instance for an anonymous user

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-security

My symfony project is set up pretty neatly, but I've been struggling with this one thing.

I have a `App/Entity/User` class which is used to populate the user information from the database

```
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->forumPermission = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->activities = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(
     *     type="string",
     *     name="salt",
     *     length=32
     * )
     */
    private $salt = "";
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(
     *     type="string",
     *     length=75,
     *     name="user_name"
     * )
     * @Assert\NotBlank(
     *     message="De gebruikersnaam moet ingevuld zijn"
     * )
     */
    private $username;
    // ...
}
```

and linked correctly in security.yaml

```
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        db_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username
```

When a user is not logged in however, they are considered anonymous.
What I would find convenient is that an anonymous user would have it's own instance of User, but instead `$this->getUser() === null`.
I understand why, but I'm stubborn:

I have a base controller that I inherit from all my other controllers:

```
abstract class BaseController extends Controller
{
    protected $logger = null;
    protected $globals = null;
    protected $translator = null;
    protected $security = null;
    /* @var $currentUser User */
    protected $currentUser = null;

    public function __construct(
        Globals $globals,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        TranslatorInterface $translator,
        Security $security
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->globals = $globals;
        $this->translator = $translator;
        $this->currentUser = $security->getUser();
    }

    protected function getUser() {
        if (!$this->currentUser instanceof User) {
            /* @var $anonForumPerm ForumPermission */
            $anonForumPerm = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(ForumPermission::class)->find(5);
            $this->currentUser = new User();
            $this->currentUser->setName('Anonymous')
                ->setSurname('User')
                ->setUsername('anon.')
                ->setForumPermission($anonForumPerm)
            ;
        }
        return $this->currentUser;
    }
    // ...
}
```

This seems to work, but the only problem I have now is twig's `app.user` which remains null.

Is there a way to push `$this->currentUser` to `app.user` in twig?
Or is there a better way to handle anonymous users?

My theory is, I want to be able to choose between `app.user` OR `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` regardless if the user has not logged in.

Some extra input would be appreciated

Comment: I don't think it is advisable to make believe an Anonymous user is the same as a real user. I'm sure there are some core functionalities that depend on a user being logged in, and if you do what you are trying to do, you are liable to get in trouble somewhere down the road. I would advise you to keep that distinction.

Comment: @Yoshimitsu, yes that would be my first thought as well. But it would be cool if I didn't have to check `app.user` on every page that makes use of it. It seems there's no way around it

Answer (score 0):

I've also struggled with this issue before and here's some extra input from my experience.

If the visitor of your website is not logged in, Symfony will give him the `AnonymousToken` which can be fetched in twig by `{{ app.token.user }}` which returns the string `anon.`

Another way you can do is just simply check if the `{{ app.user }}` is not `null`.

Comment: Hi Carol, I understand that, but my site has a forum. I always redirected users that were not logged in away from the forum. So my current code makes heavy use of `app.user`. Now I want anonymous users to at least be able to visit the forum. If I have to change all instances of `app.user` to `app.user is defined ? app.user : app.token.user`... It feels like I'm doing something wrong